# Handling clients with socket and threading in Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I've got two .py files. One is server.py and the other is GUI.py, where I'm using Tkinter for the gui. My problem is:

I can't seem to get how to write the code so that the server would get the message from the GUI and call a function from within itself that can too send and receive messages to the same thread for the client. And that all outside the handle_client fucntion.  ​

The goal here is to get two variables from the GUI, through the socket then they will be compared with the dict content from the DB and one binary or string message will indicate the GUI that those credentials are legit, and the GUI will then call a function. On the GUI side for now, I've managed to send but not receive messages afterwards.
I've read so many articles and questions and watched so many videos and I still can't figure that out.

In the code below you can see the server file contents, where there is a client_login_window function (which is called when the server receive "!CLIENT_OPEN" from the client- GUI), where I managed to get a dictionary from the database, containing all users and their respective passwords. I have a way to compare two variables with the dict's keys and values, which works but only in the client side. I also don't know how to get thinks working in the client. So.. I basically know nothing.

Hope I've explained correctly what I want to achieve, but in case I've not, please feel free to ask. Thanks you in advance! :)

[UPDATE from 16/07/2021]

server side

```py
import socket
import threading
import datetime
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import json
date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()
FORMAT = "utf-8"
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[Listening] Address: {SERVER} on {HOSTNAME}\n")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        hname = socket.gethostname()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr, hname))
        thread.start()
        print(f"ACTIVE SESSIONS: {threading.activeCount() - 1}")


def handle_client(conn, addr, hname):
    credentials = {'admin': '', 'peter': 'password1'}
    try:
        username = ""
        new_session = f"{addr} on {hname} | "
        print(new_session)
        connected = True
        connfile = conn.makefile()
        while connected:
            msg = connfile.readline().rstrip('\n')
            print(msg)
            if msg == "!DISCONNECT":
                connected = False
            if msg[:5] == "user:":
                username = msg[5:]
                if username in credentials:
                    conn.send(b"username OK...\n")
            if msg[:5] == "pass:":
                password = msg[5:]
            if msg[:4] == "done":
                if username in credentials:
                    if password == credentials[username]:
                        print(f"Sending welcome message to {addr}, {hname}")
                        conn.send(b"!COMEIN\n")
                        username = ""
                        password = ""
                    else:
                        conn.send(b"password not ok\n")
                        username = ""
                        password = ""
                else:
                    conn.send(b"username not ok\n")
                    username = ""
                    password = ""
        conn.close()
    except Exception as exp:
        print("ERROR" + str(exp))
        print("Client closed the connection...")
        return
start()
```

client side

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = "utf-8"
SERVER = "10.0.0.21"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
from_server=""


def try_connect():
    global connected
    connected = False
    try:
        client.connect(ADDR)
        connected = True
        while connected:
            from_server = client.recv(1024)
            from_server = from_server.decode()
            print(from_server)
            if from_server == "!COMEIN\n":
                second_window()
            if from_server == "username OK\n":
                pass #Indicator that the username exists
    except:
        connected = False

def second_window():
    login.destroy()
    second_win = Tk()
    login.geometry("760x370")
    lbl = Label(second_win, text="Second window")
    lbl.pack()
    second_win.mainloop()

login = Tk()
login.geometry("760x370")
username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()

def send_username(*args):
    if connected == True:
        #print("Sending username...")
        client.send(("user:" + username.get() + '\n').encode())
def send_password(*args):
    if connected == True:
        #print("Sending password...")
        client.send(("pass:" + password.get() + '\n').encode())
        client.send("done\n".encode())
        username.set("")
        password.set("")
e_username = ttk.Entry(login, width=70, textvariable=username)
e_username.pack(pady=(200, 10))
e_username.focus()
e_username.bind("<FocusOut>", send_username)
e_password = ttk.Entry(login, width=70, show="*", textvariable=password)
e_password.pack()
e_password.bind("<Return>", send_password)
threading.Thread(target=try_connect).start()
login.mainloop()
```

The saga of never-ending questions continues:

I think I solved that, but I'm pretty sure that I've done it the worst way possible. Could you point me the right way to do the following: I want the server and the client to be in constant communication, like in the login window, with the username entry, in other windows when an entry loses focus their contents to be send to the sever, validated and returned. I think that can be managed with another thread, but I think that this kind of communication and the threading don't get along so well. I may be wrong and if that is the case: Is it possible for every Toplevel of the second Tk to start a new thread in the server for that client? At the moment as you can see all the conditions are in try_connect function and I don't thinks that is the correct way, but it was the only one managed to come up with. Same goes for the server side. All the if conditions to do a specific think after specific messages are inside the handle_client function.

Also in the client, when the "!COMEIN\n" message arrives the login closes but the second_win does not open. I've done it many times: destroying the Tk and open new Tk, so then from the new Tk could open multiple if needed Toplevels.

Comment: `new_session = f"{addr} {date_time}"
NameError: name 'date_time' is not defined`

Comment: Hi, I've excluded that variable from the code but forgot to remove it from new_session. My bad. Felt irrelevant to show it. That's not the problem.

Comment: It is good that you shortened the code; it is a problem if the shortened code is not runnable - people may be less inclined to invest their time then.

Comment: I assumed, sry for that. I uptaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>         msg_lenght = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
>         if msg_lenght:
>             msg_lenght = int(msg_lenght)
>             msg = conn.recv(msg_lenght).decode(FORMAT)
> ```

You cannot rely on the message length and the message content to arrive in exactly two cleanly separated packets so that `conn.recv(HEADER)` would yield the former and `conn.recv(msg_lenght)` the latter; both may well together be returned as `msg_lenght`, and the program crash with e. g.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12!CLIENT_OPEN'
```

There are several methods to overcome this; I suggest to keep it simple, drop the length and (send and) receive the message as a line:

```
def client_login_window(conn, connfile):
    …
    conn.send(b"username:\n")
    user = connfile.readline().rstrip('\n')
    conn.send(b"password:\n")
    word = connfile.readline().rstrip('\n')
    if credentials.get(user)==word: conn.send(b"Welcome!\n")
    else:                           conn.send(b"Go away!\n")

…
    connfile = conn.makefile()
    …
            while msg := connfile.readline().rstrip('\n'):
            …
                    client_login_window(conn, connfile)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, but that is not quite what I  asking.

Comment: Actually, you didn't ask a question at all, but I presented you the reason why your approach is not working, and suggested a cure. If you are not satisfied with that, and don't want to state the reason of your dissatisfaction, I'm afraid I can't help further.

Comment: My biggest problem is that I can't figure out how when the server receives a message to call a certain function(that I managed but only to that point.... and then, inside that function to have the ability to send and receive messages. All that outside handle_client function.

Comment: To be able _to send and receive messages_ inside e. g. `client_login_window`, you just have to pass `conn` or `connfile` as a function argument.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm gonna try it soon. :)

Comment: Hi, Could you show me how to do it with connfile in my case? :D I can't seem to manage.

Comment: Hi, Once again thank you for your help. I'm beginning to understand the things already.  I updated the code in my question... Maybe I've done something wrong and I can't understand what, since I'm looking at the code for 1 hour. The problem now is that the messages are delivered to the server, as soon as the client is closed and the !DISCONNECT message is sent. The output is: !CLIENT_OPEN!DISCONNECT. The Exception I'll put into the code of my question. Could you please tell me where have I mistaken? Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Since we read the messages with `readline()`, we must also send complete lines, e. g. `send(b"!CLIENT_OPEN\n")` - and you forgot to append `.rstrip('\n')` to `msg = connfile.readline()`.

Comment: It worked... for the most part. Last question, I know I'm becoming annoying, but it's my dream for that to work. :D In the client.py file I'm using client.recv(1024) to get the messages. It's in the send() function like so:   def send(msg):/here is a new line/
    client.send(msg) /here is a new line/
    client.recv(1024) I guess that's not the right way. When I wan't to get the message from the server it doesn't show. Also once it get the OPEN_CLIENT MESSAGE THE DISCONNECT message doesn't come from the client.

Comment: If there's still a problem, I can't tell the cause from the description.

Comment: Simplified the question is: How can I check for and receive messages from the client side, with that method? The messages from client to server are sent, but the client doesn''t receive them with print(client.recv(1024)). I guess it needs the same loop as on the server side.

Comment: Though I can't be sure about the current issue without seeing the code in context, you're right that the method used on the server will also work on the other side.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with the base of the two files. I've also described the problems there. Thanks again for the help with this matter.

Comment: 1. Do you absolutely want to complicate the matter by using the OPEN_CLIENT and DISCONNECT messages? If the only sensible thing a client can do after connecting is OPEN_CLIENT, you could waive that message and proceed the server to the login right away. Similarly the server could close the connection without a DISCONNECT message when it detects the client has closed; this case has to be handled anyway.

Comment: I don't think that this method is absolutely necessary, but at the time I saw it seemed ok. The truth is that I wan't the server to be able to handle more messages, leading to functions that so that the code would be separate and clean. Those two messages are merely an example of that. I could try to use try and except to handle the exception that occurs when the client closes - thats true. What do you suggest though?

Comment: I suggest to drop the OPEN and DISCONNECT message as said above. After successful login, you can handle messages with functions as you wish.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, thanks. Can you suggest how to receive the messages from the client so that the login can be checked by the server?

Comment: 2. Since you have a login dialog in the client, the `username` and `password` prompts are unneeded. We can drop the server's `conn.send(b"username:\n")` and `conn.send(b"password:\n")` as well as the client's `if client.recv(1024) == b"username":` and `if client.recv(1024) == b"password":`, and do right away just `client.send((username.get()+'\n').encode()); client.send((password.get()+'\n').encode())`. By the way, in the test `if client.recv(1024) == b"Welcome":` you forgot the `!\n` at the end. - Definitely _another thread to run the login_window function in the server_ wasn't a good idea.

Comment: That work alright, but when I try to receive the message from the server after the client sent the app freezes. I've pasted the login func from the client in the code of the question.

Comment: Does the client print anything after you press `Login`? Besides - you didn't post the updated server code.

Comment: Hi, Updated with a whole lot of qestions, although the problem with the receiving messages is solved-ish.  :D

Comment: To begin with, in order for the server to reliably detect unorderly disconnects of the client, change the `while connected:
            msg = connfile.readline().rstrip('\n')` to the `while …` I edited in my answer.

Comment: I guess that should be in the server, but I can't understand how to handle all the places where it was connected = False to stop the while loop

Comment: Regarding the questions in the question post: From your client, I also don't get a second window displayed after the login window is destroyed. This may have to do with the repeated use of `mainloop()`, which seems unusual, but such `tkinter` issues don't fit in the scope of the question at hand and may warrant another question. What I can say is that I'd refrain from using more than one thread per client; the more threads, the more problems I expect. At the moment, I can't see why reading and handling all messages in one place wouldn't be cleaner than scattering this all over the program.

Comment: Regarding the _all the places where it was connected = False_: Ah, I overlooked this, but in the server there's only one place, and there you can change `connected = False` to `break`.

Comment: Yeah, in the not so short version of the code I left one more loop and it was messing this up, because I was looking that version and not the one that I posted here. Thanks that worked perfectly.